# How do I count each two lines in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a string variable called: `Test`
The content of `Test` is 150 lines.

I want to count each two lines and after this two lines to inser/add a new empty line to make space between each two lines.

So in index 3 to insert empty line in index 6 to insert empty line in index 9 ,12,15.
And when i get to the last line don't add after it an empty line. Only between each two lines. Not in the beginning and not in the end only between each two lines.

This is what i have: combindedString is single string variable:

```
string[] ss = combindedString.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" },
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < ss.Length; i++)
    ss[i] = ss[i].Trim();

combindedString = String.Join("\n", ss);
```

After that code which is also what i need in the end in combindedString it's content is like this:

I see many lines the first line is just text: `hello world`
Second line is date&time line: `6/16/2014`...
Third line is another text: `hello everyone`
Fourth line is again date&time: `5/16/2014`...

And so on all the lines are text and after it date&time.

I want after each text and date&time line to insert one empty space line.
So in the end the content in `combindedString` will look like:

> Hello world
>   6/16/2014
>
> Hi everyone
>   5/16/2014
>
> This is test
>   5/16/2014

Instead of how it is now without the spaces. I want to add space between each two lines:

> Hello world
>   6/16/2014
>   Hi everyone
>   5/16/2014
>   This is test
>   5/16/2014

To insert an empty/space line after each text and date&time lines.

Comment: Do you mean a string array? or is `Test` actually a single string?

Comment: `string[n]` accesses the nth char in that string. You need to split the input on newline first into a string array. Then you can loop over that and insert them and empty lines into a new list or array.

Comment: Edited my question with exatcly what i did and what i need.

Comment: musefan combindedString is a single string. Regular string not array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
string[] lines = combindedString.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" },
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0)   // i != 0 to not get blank line at the beginning
        result.AppendLine();
    result.AppendLine(lines[i].Trim());
}
combindedString = result.ToString();
```

See example [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cklWpN).

Comment: Maybe use a `StringBuilder` for the `result`?

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot easier using a `List<string>` instead of an array

```
string[] lines = new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
List<string> copyList = lines.ToList();
for(int x = copyList.Count()- 1; x > 0; x--)
{
    if(x % 2 == 0)
        copyList.Insert(x, "");
}

string combinedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, copyList);
```

**There is also the one line solution provided by Linq**

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
       lines.Select ((l,i) => (i % 2 == 1 ? l + Environment.NewLine : l)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will add a line after every second line.

```
public string InsertLines(string Test)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var lines = Test.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i % 2 == 0)
            builder.AppendLine();
        builder.AppendLine(lines[i]);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var lookup = ss
    .Concat(ss.Length % 2 == 0
        ? Enumerable.Empty<string>()
        : new [] { "" })
    .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
    .ToLookup(xn => xn.n % 2 == 0, xn => xn.x);

var query =
    lookup[true]
        .Zip(lookup[false], (o, e) => new [] { o, e, "" })
        .SelectMany(x => x);

var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, query);
```

LINQ all the way. :-)